# No puedo acceder info expresada en el DOM con Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, dom, undefined

Tengo un catálogo de productos hecho con un constructor. Todos los elementos que lo conforman están guardados en un array llamado "catalogo". Logré que esa info se expresara en el DOM usando AJAX:

```
 $.ajax({
    url: "./catalogo.html",
    success: function (html) {
        catalogo.forEach((element) => {
  
            let view = html;
            
            view = view.replaceAll ('[categoria]', element.categoria)
            view = view.replaceAll ('[nombre]', element.nombre)
            view = view.replaceAll ('[año]', element.año)
            view = view.replaceAll ('[link]', element.link)
            
            $("#ludoteca").append (view)
            
        });
    },
  });
```

El HTML que completa AJAX es este:

```
<div category= "[categoria]" id="info"> 
    [nombre] ([año]) 
</div>

<button class="btn btn-outline-primary" type="button" onclick="window.open('[link]','_blank');" >+ info</button>
```

Como resultado logro que toda la info se visualice de la mejor manera, pero luego ocurre que trato de recuperar el atributo `category` dentro de cada div y el resultado es `undefined`

Así es como trato de recuperarlo, asociando una función a un botón que tiene la class "category item". Aca el botón:

```
<div class="item" id="categories">
  <button id="mostrar"  class="category-item" >Mostrar</button>
</div>
```

Y acá la función asociada:

```
$(".category-item").click(function() {
    
  var catProd =  $(this).data('category');
  console.log(catProd);
          
});
```

Lo que entiendo es que no puede recuperar el atributo porque "no está". Trate de mover la función dentro del AJAX, pero no sirve. También trate usar `attr()` y `prop()` en lugar de `data()`, pero tampoco sirvió

Comment: ¿Podrías agregar a la pregunta el HTML de al menos uno de los `div` con la clase `category-item` pulsando en [edit]? Eso es lo que interesa ver, si no tienen ese atributo es evidente que no podrás obtener nada de algo que no existe. Y si no existe pues tienes que hacer que exista o plantear tu código de otro modo.

Comment: Ahí mostré el botón en cuestión

Comment: Saludos. No veo (en el código que compartes) el momento o línea donde asignas a `data` la información *(https://api.jquery.com/data/)*. Así mismo el `$(this).data('category')` que pones hace referencia al botón. El `undefined` es por que en ningún momento se ha definido (previo a su intento de acceder a el) el atributo `data`.

Comment: Tenés razón, estoy usando mal el data(). Cambie donde decía "category" por data-category y ahí sí me lo reconoce.

Comment: Gracias. Te recomiendo que para futuras preguntas pongas siempre un mínimo de código donde se pueda ver todo el contexto del problema. Aquí se ve claramente que el botón no tiene asignado ningún atributo `data-`, incluso me pregunto si necesitas tal atributo ¿?, pues el botón tiene aún posibilidades no usadas, como podría ser `value` por ejemplo, donde podrías guardar el dato. Generalmente los atributos `data-` se usan para guardar múltiples valores. Te recomiendo que pienses en usar primero otro tipo de atributos disponibles y si éstos se agotan pases a usar `data-`

Answer (score 0):

En el HTML que compartes falta la asignación del atributo `data-` que quieres leer, por tanto estás teniendo el *undefined*. Es preciso por tanto asignar `data-category="unValor"`  a los botones, por ejemplo:

```js
  $(".category-item").click(function() {

    var catProd = $(this).data('category');
    console.log(catProd);

  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item" id="categories">
  <button id="mostrar" class="category-item" data-category="ropa">Ropa</button>
    <button id="mostrar" class="category-item" data-category="zapatos">Zapatos</button>

</div>
```

No obstante, ten en cuenta que [como dice MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes), los atributos `data-`

> Permiten almacenar información adicional sobre un elemento HTML
> cualquiera sin tener que recurrir a artilugios tales como la
> utilización de atributos no estándar, propiedades adicionales en el
> DOM o `Node.setUserData()`.

Pero tampoco abuses de ellos sin necesidad. Por ejemplo, la categoría podría ser guardado en el atributo `value` del botón:

```js
$(".category-item").click(function() {

    var catProd = $(this).val();
    console.log(catProd);

  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item" id="categories">
  <button id="mostrar" class="category-item" value="ropa">Ropa</button>
    <button id="mostrar" class="category-item" value="zapatos">Zapatos</button>

</div>
```